# Website is not sending emails to email add on MS Exhange

Tags: email, web, exchange-server

Having problems with setting up my website to use MS Exchange to send emails. I dont want to use the hosts email system.

The MS Exhange has been set up, with email addresses created.

My webpages are using Persits.MailSender which the host supports.

Do i need to change MX records? A records?

Sorry, im not clued up with network side of things, any help would be appreciated

When i email direct, the email address on the exchange picks up the emails. BUT if i email through the website, it goes to the annoying webmail the host is provinding, and not to the exchange

I find this strange, the same email address receiving emails at different places!

Im using ASP, and I have a website set up, which has been sending emails for the last 12 months, the host has messed up (again) somewhere, but doesnt know what is wrong (as usual)

There are no errors, the email always gets sent.... but to the wrong place.

Comment: Consider that the emails may be getting dumped as spam by the exchange server, stuck in your smtp server's outgoing queue, etc...  Can you send emails to that exchange using another mail client? Far too many variables to say "do X to fix this".

Comment: Yes, the exchange is receiving emails directly, for example, if i send an email from my gmail

Answer (score 0):

I would look into actually trapping and knowing your errors. That way you can see precisely why it fails and have something to work with.  As it stands, your question isn't really answerable. No language nor framework is provided. We don't know if the mail server is confirmed to be working or accessible outside your netowrk; we don't know how your are referencing it or if you are passing user credentials; we don't know what error you're getting...

At this point, you're not debugging, you're just sort of swinging in the dark.  Find the point of failure and then research that data point to get a solution.  Debug, catch errors, log, step through your code.  All good ideas.

Comment: I understand, problem is, im not getting an error. both email accounts with the same address are receiving emails, MS Exchange when emailed directly via gmail for example, but website only sends to webmail by the host.

Comment: Im using ASP, and I have a website set up, which has been sending emails for the last 12 months, the host has messed up (again) somewhere, but doesnt know what is wrong (as usual)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out, I deleted the mail domain on the host as that was the first place the website looks to send an email. Once the mail domain was deleted the emails were sent to the external hosted mailserver MS Exchange email address. Yay!